# Too many concurrent connections ssh on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, server, bitbucket

When I upload my project to Bitbucket the Jenkins' pipeline execute several files for checking if my changes haven't broken the project. The main line is `"stderr: Received disconnect from 10.34.6.240 port 7999:12: Too many concurrent connections (250) - max. allowed: 250"`

All the error:

```
git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@bitbucket.tecnotech.com:7999/qat/sgi-linkingtool-web-test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
    
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://git@bitbucket.tecnotech.com:7999/qat/sgi-linkingtool-web-test.git

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:908)

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1123)

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1159)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:124)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@bitbucket.tecnotech.com:7999/qat/sgi-linkingtool-web-test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
    
    stdout: 
    
    stderr: Received disconnect from 10.34.6.240 port 7999:12: Too many concurrent connections (250) - max. allowed: 250
    
    Authentication failed.
    
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to increase the value of `plugin.ssh.session.max`. See corresponding section in the [Bitbucket configuration manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver065/bitbucket-server-config-properties-976163269.html#BitbucketServerconfigproperties-SSHcommandexecution)l.